# Snowflake query to create json - multiple results for single attribute

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, key-value, array-agg, object-construction

I have a table in snowflake that has three different columns being used as name type/values. These need to be mapped in an MDM tool using json. Of course, I cannot use the same attribute name more than once, or an error occurs.

| NameType1 | NameType2 | NameType3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AL_PL | Alpha Place | Alpha Place Main Store |
| BET_PL | Beta Place | Beta Place Primary Store |

The goal is to have the following:

```
 "OrgNames": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "OrgName": [
                            {
                                "value": "AL_PL"
                            }
                        ],
                        "OrgNameType": [
                            {
                                "value": "NameType1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "value": {
                        "OrgName": [
                            {
                                "value": "Alpha Place"
                            }
                        ],
                        "OrgNameType": [
                            {
                                "value": "NameType2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "value": {
                        "OrgName": [
                            {
                                "value": "Alpha Place Main Store"
                            }
                        ],
                        "OrgNameType": [
                            {
                                "value": "NameType3"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
```

I have created CTEs

```
org_ali AS (
SELECT tablespaceID
        ,DEPARTMENTID
        ,(object_construct_keep_null(
            'OrgName', array_agg(object_construct_keep_null(
            'value', src.NameType1
            )
            ),
            'OrgNameType', array_agg(object_construct_keep_null(
             'value', 'NameType1'
            )
            )
        )
        ) AS AliasName                  
FROM TABLE AS src
        GROUP BY tablespaceID,
        DEPARTMENTID,
        NameType1
```

And the in a later CTE added (with a join in place)

```
,
                'OrgNames',array_agg(object_construct_keep_null('value', org_ali.AliasName)
                ),
```

When only one result is required, this works perfectly. However, I need to replicate the value key pairs with different data under the same named struct.

I cannot seem to build this without a conflict in one of the keys. And the constraints of Snowflake is no more than 1 argument in the struct.

Clearly, there is something I am missing. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Hi - why are you creating OrgName and OrgNameType as arrays ({...]) but then only have a single value in each one?

Comment: Great question. The tool that I will be sending the final json in for ingestion requires this format.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the code, and it works great (tested in Snowflake). Just use the LISTAGG function to make it happen.

```
    SELECT
  PARSE_JSON(
    '[' ||
      LISTAGG(
        '{
          "value": {
            "OrgName": [{"value": "' || column_value || '"}],
            "OrgNameType": [{"value": "' || column_name || '"}]
          }
        }',
        ', '
      )
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_index) ||
    ']'
  )::VARIANT AS OrgNames
FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS column_index,
    column_name,
    column_value
  FROM --ENTER YOUR TABLE NAME HERE
  UNPIVOT (column_value FOR column_name IN (NameType1, NameType2, NameType3))
);
```

Comment: I've just deleted three comments because I figured out why the error was occurring; a value has double quotes in the column_value field. If I add ```REPLACE(column_value,'"','') as column_value``` to my code, the error is resolved. However, if I use ```REPLACE(column_value,'"','\"') as column_value```  the error still occurs. I'm not as familiar with PARSE JSON or LISTAGG, and cannot figure out how to allow the double quotes to display. I understand this is poor data quality, but we tend not to suppress DQ issues, but allow to surface so we know what needs to be fixed in the source. Thank you.